# SQL - Subtract 2 rows in same table using common key

Tags: sql, t-sql

Have a database with three columns - gamekey, teamed, final score. I am trying to find the score differential for each gamekey.

```
Gamekey. Teamed. Finalscore
 16      27      21
 16       7      24
 17      22      17   
 17      21      10
 18      15      9
 18      11      3
```

Desire output would be

```
Gamekey.   Scorediff
16         3
17         7
18         6
```

Comment: How is the score differential calculated? I don't see the correlation between the input and output.

Comment: Do you always have exactly two rows for each Gamekey?

Comment: BTW - I never really expect to see an answer accepted when it from userXXXXXXX with 1 rep. user1334995, prove me wrong ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want the absolute value of the difference, so you could use;

```
SELECT Gamekey, max(Finalscore) - min(Finalscore) as Scorediff
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Gamekey
```

--adding the below for validation you ran (granted the below was tested in SQL Server)

```
declare @testTable as table(Gamekey int, Teamed int, Finalscore int)

INSERT INTO @testTable values(16,27,21)
INSERT INTO @testTable values(16,7,24)
INSERT INTO @testTable values(17,22,17)   
INSERT INTO @testTable values(17,21,10)
INSERT INTO @testTable values(18,15,9)
INSERT INTO @testTable values(18,11,3)


SELECT Gamekey, max(Finalscore) - min(Finalscore) as Scorediff
FROM @testTable
GROUP BY Gamekey
```

Comment: @Oded - please explain the issue you see

Comment: Sorry misread the question - I thought teamd was involved... my mistake.

Comment: BTW Ian Nelson has a good point.  I am assuming two rows for each GameKey in the input as provided by the OP

Comment: Looks like an OK assumption to make (a game is between 2 teams...)

Comment: Assumption was correct - always 2 rows per game. Thanks to all for answering!

Answer (score 1):

```
Create table Shop
(
    ItemCode varchar(10)not null,
    ShopName Varchar(50) not null,
    Items varchar(50) not null,
    Quantity int not null,
    OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),  
    UpdateDate varchar(11)not null
)
GO

Create Table Product 
(
    ProductCode varchar(10)Primary key,
    ShopName varchar(50),
    Product varchar(50),
    Quantity int ,
    UnitPrice money ,
    Defects int ,
    Remainders int ,
    TotalPrice money ,
    Benefit money ,
    OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    UpdateDate varchar(11)
)
GO
Create Table ProductSold 
(
    ShopName varchar(50)not null,
    Product varchar(50) not null,
    Quantity int not null,
    UnitPrice money not null,
    TotalPrice money not null,
    OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE() 
)
```

1. I want to subtract from Product (Remainders) when Shop (Quantity) table insert that into its table.
2. I want to subtract from Shop (Quantity) table when ProductSold (Quantity) insertion is than into the table.

Comment: How does this answer the question?